# Hide contents in environment but keep whitespace

Tags: environments, conditionals

I have a custom environment `\newenvironment{mathsolution}` that contains content that I want to hide based on the switch `\showmathtrue` and `\showmathfalse`.  The code I have for this conditional is the following:

```
\newenvironment{mathsolution}{
\setbox0\vbox\bgroup} % store solution in box 0
{\egroup              % end of box
\ifshowmath
    \par\box0         % display box
\else
    \vskip\ht0        % whitespace of height of box
\fi
}
```

I am attempting to keep the exact whitespace of the box when the content is hidden but this is not happening.

**Example of the problem**

Notice in the image below, the first math solution spacing is close but not quite exact.  In the second problem, I am using an `adjustbox` and a `minipage` and **all of the whitespace is ignored**.

[image]

**What I Need**

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=1.00in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}    % Equations
\usepackage{adjustbox}

% LONG (MATH) SOLUTIONS
\newif\ifshowmath     % use \newif to define switches
\newenvironment{mathsolution}{
\setbox0\vbox\bgroup} % store solution in box 0
{\egroup              % end of box
\ifshowmath
    \par\box0         % display box
\else
    \vskip\ht0        % whitespace of height of box
\fi
}

%\showmathtrue
\showmathfalse

\begin{document}

Some math problem stated here.
\begin{mathsolution}
$$ 1.0\times 10^{1} \left ( \dfrac{1}{10^{1}} \right ) = 1 $$
\end{mathsolution}

Some other math problem stated here.
\begin{mathsolution}
\adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}{0.43\linewidth}
\begin{align*}
x_1 &= 1.000  \\
y_1 &= \left ( \dfrac{1}{2}\right )   \left ( a - b \right ) \\
    &= 2.000 \\
x_2 &=~? \\
y_2 &= \left ( \dfrac{1}{2}\right )   \left ( b - a \right ) \\
    &= 2.000 \\
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
}
\hfill
\adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}{0.55\linewidth}
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{c}{d} = \dfrac{e}{f}  \longrightarrow
c   &= \dfrac{d\times e}{f} \\
    &= 3.000
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
}
\end{mathsolution}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

Note: Changing the text to white is not an option.

Comment: Don't forget to include \dp0.  A second \vskip is actually faster than `\dimexpr \ht0+\dp0\relax`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This modification of your MWE fixes the problem:

```
\usepackage{environ}
\newif\ifshowmath     % use \newif to define switches
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\NewEnviron{mathsolution}{%
\sbox{\mybox}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\BODY\end{minipage}}%
}[\ifshowmath\par\usebox{\mybox}%
\else\par\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\vspace*{\dimexpr\ht\mybox+\dp\mybox\relax}\end{minipage}\fi]
```

As you can see:

- I used the `environ` package, which makes this kinf of job more easy
- I didn't used `adjustbox`, which IMO is not needed here
- I changed your use of TeX primitive to LaTeX commands
  [image]